# Create-React-App with TypeScript failing to compile after importing Semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I've created a new React app by running `npx create-react-app@latest --typescript .` and I've run the project using `npm start` and it all works as expected. I ran `npm install semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css` and that installs correctly.

But when I add `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';` to `index.tsx` as instructed, I get a `failed to compile error`.

Here's my `index.tsx` file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

Everything else is untouched.

If I remove `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';` from line 6 of `index.tsx` it compiles correctly. I'm guessing this is a Webpack issue, but I'm new to Webpack and I'm not sure how to solve the issue. I've tried setting the project up from scratch again but I get the same results.

I'm using `react 17.0.2`, `react scripts 5.0.0`, `semantic-ui-react 2.0.4` and `typescript 4.5.4`. Is there something obvious that I'm missing that would fix this?

And here is the error code I get:

```
Failed to compile.

Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "data:" URIs.
assets by path static/ 9.45 KiB
  asset static/js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_js.chunk.js 6.88 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
  asset static/media/logo.6ce24c58023cc2f8fd88fe9d219db6c6.svg 2.57 KiB [emitted] (auxiliary name: main)
asset index.html 1.62 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 429 bytes [emitted]
Entrypoint main (2.57 KiB) = 1 auxiliary asset
cached modules 2.72 MiB (javascript) 1.66 MiB (asset) 31.4 KiB (runtime) [cached] 150 modules
runtime modules 54 bytes 1 module
modules by layer 4.38 KiB (javascript) 1 bytes (asset)
  ./src/index.tsx 1.82 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./src/App.tsx 2.51 KiB [built] [code generated]
  data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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 42 bytes (javascript) 1 bytes (asset) [built] [1 error]

ERROR in data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,AAEAAAAOAIAAAwBgT1MvMj3hSQEAAADsAAAAVmNtYXDQEhm3AAABRAAAAUpjdnQgBkn/lAAABuwAAAAcZnBnbYoKeDsAAAcIAAAJkWdhc3AAAAAQAAAG5AAAAAhnbHlm32cEdgAAApAAAAC2aGVhZAErPHsAAANIAAAANmhoZWEHUwNNAAADgAAAACRobXR4CykAAAAAA6QAAAAMbG9jYQA4AFsAAAOwAAAACG1heHAApgm8AAADuAAAACBuYW1lzJ0aHAAAA9gAAALNcG9zdK69QJgAAAaoAAAAO3ByZXCSoZr/AAAQnAAAAFYAAQO4AZAABQAIAnoCvAAAAIwCegK8AAAB4AAxAQIAAAIABQMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUGZFZABA6ADoAQNS/2oAWgMLAE8AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAAAAMAAAAcAAEAAAAAAEQAAwABAAAAHAAEACgAAAAGAAQAAQACAADoAf//AAAAAOgA//8AABgBAAEAAAAAAAAAAAEGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAADpAKYABUAHEAZDwEAAQFCAAIBAmoAAQABagAAAGEUFxQDEisBFAcBBiInASY0PwE2Mh8BATYyHwEWA6QP/iAQLBD+6g8PTBAsEKQJiywJSuwJSotsCcsICBHICCwAkVjsAFFYmAjYTgjIIpVWCBHICCwAkVjsAFFYmAjYTgbIVktsCgssQAFRVRYALAIo4IyFZLbA1LLAAFiCwCEMgLkcjRyNhIGCwIGBmsIBiIyAgPIo4LbA2LCMgLkawAiVGUlggPFkusSYBFCstsDcsIyAuRrACJUZQWCA8WS6xJgEUKy2wOCwjIC5GsAIlRlJYIDxZIyAuRrACJUZQWCA8WS6xJgEUKy2wOSywMCsjIC5GsAIlRlJYIDxZLrEmARQrLbA6LLAxK4ogIDywBCNCijgjIC5GsAIlRlJYIDxZLrEmARQrsARDLrAmKy2wOyywABawBCWwBCYgLkcjRyNhsAZFKyMgPCAuIzixJgEUKy2wPCyxCAQlQrAAFrAEJbAEJSAuRyNHI2EgsAQjQrAGRSsgsGBQWCCwQFFYswIgAyAbswImAxpZQkIjIEewBEOwgGJgILAAKyCKimEgsAJDYGQjsANDYWRQWLACQ2EbsANDYFmwAyWwgGJhsAIlRmE4IyA8IzgbISAgRiNHsAArI2E4IVmxJgEUKy2wPSywMCsusSYBFCstsD4ssDErISMgIDywBCNCIzixJgEUK7AEQy6wJistsD8ssAAVIEewACNCsgABARUUEy6wLCotsEAssAAVIEewACNCsgABARUUEy6wLCotsEEssQABFBOwLSotsEIssC8qLbBDLLAAFkUjIC4gRoojYTixJgEUKy2wRCywCCNCsEMrLbBFLLIAADwrLbBGLLIAATwrLbBHLLIBADwrLbBILLIBATwrLbBJLLIAAD0rLbBKLLIAAT0rLbBLLLIBAD0rLbBMLLIBAT0rLbBNLLIAADkrLbBOLLIAATkrLbBPLLIBADkrLbBQLLIBATkrLbBRLLIAADsrLbBSLLIAATsrLbBTLLIBADsrLbBULLIBATsrLbBVLLIAAD4rLbBWLLIAAT4rLbBXLLIBAD4rLbBYLLIBAT4rLbBZLLIAADorLbBaLLIAATorLbBbLLIBADorLbBcLLIBATorLbBdLLAyKy6xJgEUKy2wXiywMiuwNistsF8ssDIrsDcrLbBgLLAAFrAyK7A4Ky2wYSywMysusSYBFCstsGIssDMrsDYrLbBjLLAzK7A3Ky2wZCywMyuwOCstsGUssDQrLrEmARQrLbBmLLA0K7A2Ky2wZyywNCuwNystsGgssDQrsDgrLbBpLLA1Ky6xJgEUKy2waiywNSuwNistsGsssDUrsDcrLbBsLLA1K7A4Ky2wbSwrsAhlsAMkUHiwARUwLQAAAEu4AMhSWLEBAY5ZuQgACABjILABI0SwAyNwsgQoCUVSRLIKAgcqsQYBRLEkAYhRWLBAiFixBgNEsSYBiFFYuAQAiFixBgFEWVlZWbgB/4WwBI2xBQBEAAA=
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "data:" URIs.
    at /Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:825:25
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Object.processResource (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:822:8)
    at processResource (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:220:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:171:10)
    at runLoaders (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:812:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:956:15)
    at /Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1367:12
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css 22:37-5903
 @ ./node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css 8:6-230 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-200 83:0-200 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64 61:4-74:5
 @ ./src/index.tsx 9:0-42

ERROR in [entry] [initial]
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
during rendering of asset asset/inline|data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
during rendering of asset asset/inline|data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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
    at /Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/asset/AssetModulesPlugin.js:183:30
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:12:16)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compilation.getRenderManifest (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:4439:36)
    at /Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:4459:22
    at symbolIterator (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3482:9)
    at timesSync (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2297:7)
    at Object.eachLimit (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3463:5)
    at Compilation.createChunkAssets (/Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:4452:12)
    at /Users/eamon/projects/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3095:14

webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 2 errors in 1597 ms
Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
Issues checking in progress...
No issues found.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the same [issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/4287) mentioned by @stanislas, the fix is to remove an extra semicolon from semantic.css (or semantic.min.css):

*The main reason for this is an extra ";" at line 19990 of semantic.css
If removed, everything goes fine.*

```js
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Step';
  src: url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,AAEAAAA... // this line
}
```

While this solution works, I would caution that Semantic-UI has been unmaintained for several years now. [Fomantic-UI](https://fomantic-ui.com) is the community fork that is maintained and incorporates both bug fixes and additional features like toasts.

FYI, this bug was recently discovered so it exists in the current release version of Fomantic-UI (2.8.8), but it has been fixed in the code base and tagged for the next release.

Comment: Search x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8 in semantic.min.css and you will find 
     x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64

Remove one semicolon between utf-8 and base64. It will be now 
     x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64

Answer (score 14):

I did it the following way.
Issue is actually solved in Semantic UI CSS repository. However latest version 2.4.1 does not include it. So, just use Github repo in your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
...,
"semantic-ui-css": "git+https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS.git"
},
```

Webpack build succeeds.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from this issue:
[CSS import breaks webpack 5 compilation](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/4287)
I believe this is an issue with Semantic-UI-React and Webpack 5 (which is used by Create-React-App).

The final answer in that issue is a suggestion to switch to Fomantic-UI

> This should be reported into the upstream repo: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI. The problem is that it's dead  Reasonable solution is to switch to https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI.

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/4287#issuecomment-935897619

Answer (score 4):

I tried all of above solutions but only  [this link](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/7073#:%7E:text=This%20issue%20is%20extremely%20annoying%2C%20to%20workaround%20it%20I%20created%20%40semantic%2Dui%2Dreact/css%2Dpatch%2C%20works%20with%20semantic%2Dui%2Dcss%20%26%20semantic%2Dui%2Dless.) solved my problem

I use react version 5.0.0.

First I installed this:

```
yarn add --dev @semantic-ui-react/css-patch
# or
npm install --dev @semantic-ui-react/css-patch
```

Second I add this line in "package.json" file:

```
{
 "scripts": {
   "postinstall": "semantic-ui-css-patch"
 }
}
```

And then I removed extra ";" from

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Step';
  src: url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,AAEAAAAOAIAAAw... // this line
}
```

in "semantic-ui-css/semantic.css" file.

I hope it solve your problem like me.

Answer (score 3):

As a @Stanislas I believe this is an issue with Semantic-UI-React and Webpack 5 (which is used by Create-React-App).

At the moment the solution is to connect semantic-ui-css via CDN (no bundler)

Just add this link tag to the  after initializing React in your index.html file.

index.html

```
<body>
  <!-- ... other HTML ... -->
  <!-- ... Load React ... -->

  <link
    async
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2/dist/semantic.min.css"
  />

  <!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script src="like_button.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This does not address the problem directly. He's trying to fix the compilation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Removing:   `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'` and connect it via CDN fix the compilation

Comment: Hi @TimcuAlexei, thanks for contributing! I think your answer is more of a workaround, as it doesn't result in compiling Semantic-UI-CSS into the webpack bundle.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is use **Fomantic-UI**  that is a fork of semantic.
This is currently maintained.

[Fomantic-UI](https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI)

so, you can install, and then use it.

```js
npm install fomantic-ui
```

Here is te official Fomantic:
[Getting Started](https://fomantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html)

And here is a tutorial for implementation and more info about Fomantic:
[Medium - Fomantic](https://medium.com/@fomantic/setting-up-fomantic-ui-with-react-f701b68f736c)

Why you should use Fomantic?
because Semantic development has come to a standstill and there were multiple issues started questioning the development.

Answer (score 1):

After deleting one of the semi-colon from the css, you need to delete the ".cache" folder in your node modules before compiling again to make it work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way :

Install **css-patch** with this command :

```
npm install --dev @semantic-ui-react/css-patch
```

Then in the **node_modules** folder delete these folders

```
.bin
.cache
```

Then run this command again :

```
npm install
```